# Hide WooCommerce admin submenu "Home" from shop manager

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, admin, user-roles

I would like to hide a submenu 'home' in WooCommerce from shop manager.

I can hide/disable the `wc-admin` with the following code:

```
function AtoJ_remove_menus() {
    if (current_user_can( 'shop_manager' )) {
        // WooCommerce
        remove_submenu_page( 'woocommerce', 'wc-admin' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'AtoJ_remove_menus', 999 );
```

But if I do it that way, it also disables the permission to access the WooCommerce Analytics admin section for shop manager.

[image]

Comment: both use as base wc-admin this is why you cant access analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the Admin WooCommerce "Home" page (only) for specific user role, we can hide WooCommerce "Home" submenu item and redirect the related request to WooCommerce "Orders" page:

```php
add_action( 'admin_head', 'disable_admin_woocommerce_home_fur_css' );
function disable_admin_woocommerce_home_fur_css() {
    $targeted_role = 'administrator'; // Here define the user role
    if ( current_user_can( $targeted_role ) ) :
    ?><style> li.toplevel_page_woocommerce ul li.wp-first-item {display:none !important;}</style><?php
    endif;
}


add_action( 'admin_menu', 'disable_admin_woocommerce_home_for_user_role', 999 );
function disable_admin_woocommerce_home_for_user_role() {
    global $submenu;
    $targeted_role = 'administrator'; // Here define the user role
    if ( current_user_can( $targeted_role ) ) {
        if ( isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'wc-admin' && ! isset($_GET['path']) ) {
            wp_redirect( admin_url('edit.php?post_type=shop_order') );
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

It will allow shop manager to access Analytics section.

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you, Dharman and LoicTheAztec.
It seems that redirect "wp_redirect( admin_url( 'edit.php?post_type=shop_order') didn't work once I accessed Analytics section then access Woocommerce section. It goes to "Home" page in Woocommerce section. I guess there is a problem with timing of $_GET['page'] runs? The code does not refer 'url' of Woocommerce section but that of Analytics section? I don't know what to do.　
Thank you for your continued cooperation